# How to get the eventid of the event created using the calendar internt in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, google-calendar-api

I created an event using the calendar intent. With the code below.

```
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
        .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
        .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");
    startActivity(intent);
```

How will i get the event id of the event that i just created?